# solve with PlannerTerminationCondition missing from ROS OMPL

Tags: path-planning, arm-navigation, ompl-ros-interface, pr2-arm-navigation, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that the method `virtual bool solve (const base::PlannerTerminationCondition &ptc)` is missing from `ompl::geometric::SimpleSetup` in the ROS package. [Here](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/classompl_1_1geometric_1_1SimpleSetup.html) is the OMPL reference, and [here](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/ompl/html/classompl_1_1geometric_1_1SimpleSetup.html) is the ROS reference without this method.

I am trying to run several planners in parallel, so I am modifying the call to solve in `ompl_ros_planning_group` (in ompl_ros_interface) to take a PlannerTerminationCondition object  as an argument so that all planners can be terminated as soon as one finishes planning.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29899/solve-with-plannerterminationcondition-missing-from-ros-ompl/) by [robbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/1365/robbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2012-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Robbie,

This has been corrected for ROS fuerte. I apologize for this oversight! If you would like to use this in electric, you can try to  port the new ompl library.

A package is provided here:
svn co https://rice-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/rice-ros-pkg/ompl ompl

Ioan

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2012-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2